# GAE TaskQueue error “taskqueue.BulkAdd failed”

Tags: google-app-engine

Following the documenation here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/taskqueue/push/example

I decided to do a little testing of TaskQueues within my laravel application. Here is my currecnt test code:

```
    $task = new PushTask('/GoogleQueueTest/21',
        ['name' => 'john doe', 'action' => 'send_reminder']);
    $task_name = $task->add();

   return $task_name;
```

resulting in:

```
Remote implementation for taskqueue.BulkAdd failed
```

after alot of searching I cant seem to find why this is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

At this time the only guide available [for running Laravel on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible) is intended for the Flexible environment, which is most likely what you are running on. If that is so do note that the guide you are following is intended for App Engine Standard and that there is no current equivalent for App Engine Flexible, though you can apply to be whitelisted for the Cloud Tasks API which does work on App Engine Flexible. To do so read the disclaimer on top of [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/rest/tasks).